# Setting a monthly Budget

Tags: salesforce, apex

So I am building a budgeting app for a Salesforce project and I was wondering if there was a way to automatically set a Budget every month.

I have 3 objects: Budget, Account(Custom for finances), Transaction

I suppose I could write a method that subtracts money from Account and adds it to budget but that still doesn't address the fact that I want it to update every month.

```
public void setFoodBudget() {
        //This.Budget = [SELECT BudgetLimit 
                      //FROM Budget__c
                      //WHERE BudgetCategory = 'Food'];
            FoodBudget = 600;
    }
```

If I were to do it manually every month then I could use the query I commented out

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to see schedule batch
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IEIhQAO

Comment: This seems to be more like a comment but not an answer. Try elaborating the answer.